# linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1

Tags: undefined-reference, multiversx

I am writing integrations tests with the **MultiversX Rust testing framework**.
So, I am running `cargo test`. But it throws this error:

```
note: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
          (.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Using [this similar issue](https://github.com/acschaefer/ray_tracing/issues/3) as a starting point, I would say that the problem is that your tests are configured as a rust binary, and so the compiler expects a main function.

Try to re-create your integration test cargo package as a library, by providing the `--lib` argument to the `cargo new` command. Not providing that argument creates a binary by default, according to [the documentation on `cargo new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-new.html).